# Can't resolve outer reference to global variable because of inner reference

Tags: python, flask

I Have the following code:

```
    l_sortedQueue = sorted(l_queue, key=lambda i: i['priority'])

    for i, d in enumerate(l_sortedQueue):
        if d['key'] == some_value:
            l_queue= l_sortedQueue.insert(n_queue_position, l_sortedQueue.pop(i))
```

So I'm basically trying to move one of the dictionary entries in l_queue into a new index while shifting all the other values over one but because of how the data is organized in the list, I had to do it this way (sorting the list based on a 'priority' value before moving the item to a new index). For some reason however, when I reference l_queue within the for loop as in this line:

```
l_queue = l_sortedQueue.insert(n_queue_position, l_sortedQueue.pop(i))
```

The OUTER reference to l_queue becomes unresolved, and the inner reference refers to a new local variable instead of the global list variable. Without this inner reference, it properly references the global variable however. Why is this? How do I get the inner and outer reference to l_queue to reference the global list variable?

Not sure if it is relevant, but this code comes from a flask function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try printing this line: `l_sortedQueue.insert(n_queue_position, l_sortedQueue.pop(i))`. You will see that it prints to `None`. This is because insert is a function, which doesn't return a value. So what you think you're doing is assigning `l_SortedQueue` to `l_queue`, but what you're actually doing is overwriting your `l_queue` list with the `None`.

What you should change it to:

```
sortedQueue.insert(n_location, sortedQueue.pop())
que = sortedQueue
```

However, it looks like you're looping in a pretty hacky way which I'm not really following. I think there are better solution to your problem than this solution though.